# How to limit inserts to one row per user per month?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I would like to make a monthly contest. I have Users and Products. Each user can vote for products he/she likes the most this month. My vote table looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| user    | product   | date       |
+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1       | 1         | 2018-09-03 |
| 1       | 2         | 2018-09-03 |
| 1       | 2         | 2018-08-28 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

A user can like the same product but *not* in the same month.

My problem is that I can't figure out a valid Primary Key to prevent duplicate votes.

If I use PK `(user,product)`, a user cannot vote more than one time for the same product. If I use PK `(user,product,date)`, a user can vote the same product once a day.

How can I prevent duplicate votes within the same month?

*Note*: `date` should be a valid `DateTime` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not allow functions in keys, only column references. So if you want to restrict by a UNIQUE key, you need another column that would contain only the year and month for the event. The easiest and most straightforward approach is to reduce the `date` value to something like `YYYY-MM-01`. If you are using MySQL 5.7 or newer, you can declare that column as generated and define an expression converting the day part to the constant 01 value.

```
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| user    | product   | date       | rdate      |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1       | 1         | 2018-09-03 | 2018-09-01 |
| 1       | 2         | 2018-09-03 | 2018-09-01 |
| 1       | 2         | 2018-08-28 | 2018-08-01 |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

And now you can create the `UNIQUE INDEX permonth (user, product, rdate)`. This is the uniqueness established on the physical level.

On the logical level uniqueness can be achieved by (at least) two common ways.

First, you can define a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that would perform extended comparison of the dates and decline to insert a duplicate. But triggers are not a very clean and easy tool because of their implicitness, and my advise is to avoid triggers if possible.

The more robust way is to wrap the insert statement into a stored routine and perform `call SafeVoteInsert( userID, productID, date )` instead of plain `INSERT vote VALUES ...`.

Comment: You could use `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)` as the generated column's expression. It returns a number in the form of `YYYYMM`, which would be perfectly sufficient for the required constraint.